# What is the limit of Hadoop Distributed Cache Size?

Tags: caching, hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop, i heard that Distributed Cache Size is max 10GB. Is this correct? What if i have size more than 10 GB, Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 3):

By default, cache size is 10GB. If you want more memory configure `local.cache.size` in `mapred-site.xml` for bigger value.

Reason not to do it: It's better to keep a few MBs of data in Distributed Cache. Otherwise it will affect the performance of your application.

Comment: Is there a maximum size beyond which hadoop will complain ?, the mapred-site.xml is a per node configuration so what if one node1 has say 5 gb configured and another node 2 has say 10gb and my Distributed cache size is configured as 10 gb and i add a 7 gb file into the cache how do you think it will behave ?

Comment: `local.cache.size` has been long deprecated:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7184